# Nav menu moves down when .slideToggle is used on div above it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

I am trying to make a nav menu for part of a practice website, and I made an animation that basically slides down a green div when one of the menu options are hovered over, but once that happens the whole nav menu slides down. which I do not want. I tried changing the nav menus position to absolute, but then it looses its position, and I can't re-position it. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Here is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaHurlburt/hwja641e/) version.

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav_animations">
    <li class="nav_square home_square" id="greenHome"></li>
</ul>
<ul id="navlist">
    <li class="navlistitems" id="home">Home</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#nav_animations {
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    bottom:13px;
}
#greenHome {
    display:none;
}
.nav_square {
    background-color:green;
    width:100px;
    height:15px;
    z-index:22;
    position:relative;
}
#navlist {
    display:inline;
    font-family: 'Dhurjati', sans-serif;
    font-size:45px;
    position:relative;
}
.navlistitems {
    display:inline;
    padding:50px;
    color:black;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#home').hover(function(){
        $('#greenHome').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

PS: Yes I do have the JQuery library linked in my actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty solution using your work is as follows below. If you wanted the green dropdown to be below the parent nav item, you should add ul#nav_animations inside the li.navlistitems. That's what I've done below. I also modified your CSS a little to take this into consideration.

And here is a JSFiddle I threw together for you: http://jsfiddle.net/84amnjz7/1/

CSS:

```
#navlist {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: 'Dhurjati', sans-serif;
    font-size: 45px;
    position: relative;
    }
    .navlistitems {
        position: relative;
        padding: 25px 0 0;
        display:block;
        float: left;
        color: #000;
        }

        #nav_animations {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
            width: 100%;
            }
            #greenHome {
                display: none;
                }
            .nav_square {
                background-color: green;
                width: 100%;
                height: 15px;
                z-index: 22;
                position: relative;
                }
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#home').hover(function(){
        $('#greenHome').stop(true, true).slideToggle('fast'); /* ADDED .stop(true, true) */
    });
});
```

Modified HTML:

```
<ul id="navlist">
    <li class="navlistitems" id="home">Home
        <ul id="nav_animations">
            <li class="nav_square home_square" id="greenHome"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That looks good but I want the green bar to be above the nav menu.

Comment: I'll modify my solution in a moment then. I was assuming the green bar would be a part of the subnav that would appear. Give me 5 minutes.

Comment: Here's an updated JSFiddle. Your CSS needed quite a bit of change: http://jsfiddle.net/84amnjz7/1/ I'll now update the solution I gave.